# Markdown Hexadecimal color

Tags: hex, styles, markdown

Is there any simple way with markdown if I put a hexadecimal, I put the color?
For example if I put:
background color: #B68A65, just by placing the HEX next to it, I put the color?
background color:  #B68A65.

(something similar to what we normally see in our CSS)

Comment: Not in Markdown itself, but I believe both GitHub and GitLab do something like this. What is the specific renderer that you are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular: "**Post the question and respond to feedback** After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"